# How to get data attribute from several div with same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several `div` with same `class name`. I need to take `data attribute` from these `div's`. I had tried some code and result is getting. But I am not sure this approach is good or bad to get `data("cartid")`. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
if ($(".forComments").length > 0) {
  var cartCommentsId = [];

  $(".forComments").each(function() {
    cartCommentsId.push($(this).data("cartid"));
  });

  $.each(cartCommentsId, function(key, item) {
    console.log(item);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group forComments" data-cartid="123454535345">
<div class="form-group forComments" data-cartid="86754546646">
<div class="form-group forComments" data-cartid="43434343434">
```

Comment: Your code works, please create a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Yes, you can use `console.log($(".forComments").map( (i,v) => $(v).data( "cartid" ) ).get());`

Comment: `$(this).attr("data-cartid")`?

Comment: @guradio always use `data()` when getting/setting `data` attributes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @gurvinder372 This is really good approach thank you.

Comment: @samsam just be wary as it won't work at all in IE due to the arrow function

Comment: @Huangism It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SamOnela seems to be on track for code review to me

Comment: @Huangism like I said in my original comment it is okay to recommend CR - please read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313266/1575353) for more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine, so there's nothing inherently wrong with your approach; although you're missing the `</div>` tags.

If you wanted to simplify the logic you can remove the `if` condition and use `map()` to build the array:

```js
var cartCommentsId = $(".forComments").map(function() {
  return $(this).data("cartid");
}).get();

console.log(cartCommentsId);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group forComments" data-cartid="123454535345"></div>
<div class="form-group forComments" data-cartid="86754546646"></div>
<div class="form-group forComments" data-cartid="43434343434"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help